# Overall CMRR of analog front-end

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, noise, instrumentation-amplifier, cmrr

My analog front end input consists of a chain of (instrumentation amplifier + differential amplifier + and ADC).

[image]

Is the CMRR of the overall chain only considered based on the first element that is the instrumentation amplifier or the overall CMRR of each stage is combined for a first stage total CMRR?

That being said, assuming my first stage has 100dB CMRR, if my ADC is 70dB how would that affect the overall performance?

Comment: InAmps are usually single-ended output. A mere signal path is shown here; are we to understand the filter stages represent a fully differential path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CMRR means that a tiny part of the input common mode voltage will be converted to the differential mode signal output. Therefore, subsequent stages cannot remove this common-mode-error anymore, because it has been turned into a "legitimate" differential mode signal.

That also means that the first stages need very high CMRR, whereas the last stage doesn't matter that much.

In your scenario, you can expect an input referred CMRR of around 100 dB. However, if your first stage had 70 dB and the ADC had 100 dB, then the overall CMRR would be around 70 dB.

Comment: And to add to this -- note that CMRR is maximum near DC, and typically dropping with frequency. Check that CMRR is sufficient by the point the LPF cuts in.